# Using webapp basic for different domains and repos

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have 5 azure webapp instances and the price tier for each is **Shared D1**. Each are directed with different **sub domain** and **git repo**.

Now I would like to upgrade to **Basic B1** price tier, so that I can use my SSL cert and some extra features.

My question is can I group all the 5 webapp into one instance, with different git repos and domains?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have an unlimited number of Web Apps in a Basic B1 plan.  Look at the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is positive. You can leverage an App Service Plan, which represents a set of features and capacity that you can share across multiple apps in Azure App Service.

Apps in the same subscription and geographic location can share a plan. All the apps sharing a plan can leverage all the capabilities and features defined by the plan's tier(**Free**, **Shared**, **Basic**, **Standard** and **Premium**).

All apps associated with a given plan run on the resources defined by the plan. For example, if your plan is configured to use two "small" instances in the standard service tier, all apps associated with that plan will run on both instances and will have access to the standard service tier functionality.

Please refer to [Azure App Service plans in-depth overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/) for details.